# Where to begin with the Rayleigh Dissipation Function?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, education, dissipation

I'm a final year student of mechanical engineering. Calculus of Variations isn't a part of our syllabus.

I'm trying to understand the Rayleigh Dissipation function, and I understand that this is a part of Lagrangian Mechanics, but I've tried to understand the latter by reading *Classical Mechanics* by Goldstein, and *Mechanics* by Landau-Lifshitz, to no avail. The material on youtube either skims the surface or is incomprehensible. Any idea what the best way to learn Lagrangian Mechanics is for a complete beginner?

Comment: I would suggest you to go through Goldstein once more and this time try to solve the problems if you haven't, because this way you will know how much of it you actually understood.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the book from Nolting "Theoretical Physics 2 (Analytical Mechanics)". Its a solid book for beginners.